# CSS focus system color

Tags: css

css has a bunch of responsive keywords for system colors. What is the keyword for the focus color?

Running the snippet below, when the `<input>` element has the focus it has a light blue outline which may be a different color depending on the user's color preference settings and the OS and browser

I want to set the `<div>`'s outline, currently red, to the same color as the `<input>`'s outline. What [CSS system color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#system_colors) do I use?

[image]

Example

```js
document.querySelector('input').focus();
```

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

.form {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form:focus-within {
  /* want to replace "red" with the system color for focus */
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.system-colors-example {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: field;
  color: fieldtext;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" value="hell-o-whirled">
</div>

<div class="system-colors-example">
  example of system colors<br>
  colors here should match input text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-webkit-focus-ring-color` for Chrome / Safari and `-moz-mac-focusring` for Firefox.

```js
document.querySelector('input').focus();
```

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

.form {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}


  .form:focus-within {
     outline: 5px auto -moz-mac-focusring; /* Firefox */
     outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; /* Webkit, Safari */
  }


.system-colors-example {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: field;
  color: fieldtext;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" value="hell-o-whirled">
</div>

<div class="system-colors-example">
  example of system colors<br>
  colors here should match input text
</div>
```